# gdalwarp ignoring multiple srcnodata values?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, nodata, resampling

I'm trying to resample an in image in the MODIS sinusoidal projection. There are several fill/ NoData values that I want to exclude in the resampling. The data are unsigned 16-bit integer values. [A sample source image can be downloaded here.](http://files.ntsg.umt.edu/data/NTSG_Products/MOD16/MOD16A3.105_MERRAGMAO/Y2014/); I'm using the `ET_1km` layer in the 2014 image: `MOD16A3.A2014365.h11v05.105.2015034131802.hdf`.

Because the source is an HDF4 file, I initially use `gdal_translate` to built a VRT.

```
gdal_translate -of vrt -ot UInt16 HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"/path/to/file/MOD16A3.A2014365.h11v05.105.2015034131802.hdf":MOD_Grid_MOD16A3:PET_1km ~/Downloads/temp.vrt
```

Then, I use `gdal_merge.py` (because I really want to merge multiple VRTs to build a global mosaic) to output a GeoTIFF.

```
gdal_merge.py -of "GTiff" -o ~/Downloads/temp.tiff ~/Downloads/temp.vrt
```

Finally, I use `gdalwarp` to resample/ reproject the image. The target projection here is a global EASE-Grid 2.0. **Note I have multiple `srcnodata` values that I want to map to a single NoData value in the output.**

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:6933" -r bilinear -tr 1000 1000 \
-te -17367530.450 -7301459.170 17336469.550 7314540.830 \ 
-srcnodata "65535 65534 65533 65532 65531 65530 65529" \
-dstnodata 65535 -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=6 -ot UInt16 \
~/Downloads/temp.tiff ~/Downloads/temp_warped.tiff
```

**Unfortunately, the warped file has resampled the `srcnodata` values.** It has set the correct output NoData value (65535) but there are still unmasked values from the `srcnodata` array and they have contaminated adjacent, resampled pixels. These values are much higher than the expected range, so they're pretty obviously affected by these unmasked `srcnodata` values.

Reading the array in with GDAL/NumPy, I can verify that I'm asking `gdalwarp` to mask the right values; the three highest are among my `srcnodata` values and nothing else comes close:

```
>>> np.unique(arr)[6300:]
array([18227, 18228, 18230, 18250, 18258, 18259, 18268, 18271, 18275,
       18278, 18281, 18282, 18288, 18292, 18299, 18302, 18304, 18306,
       18315, 18319, 18320, 18322, 18326, 18338, 18341, 18352, 18355,
       18365, 18373, 18385, 18389, 18435, 18465, 18479, 18504, 18535,
       18552, 18555, 18556, 18559, 18561, 18566, 18572, 18594, 18614,
       18622, 18637, 18640, 18735, 18738, 18845, 18867, 18868, 18906,
       19100, 65530, 65533, 65534], dtype=uint16)
```

**Is there something special about specifying multiple `srcnodata` values?** I don't often use more than one. I guess until I figure this out I'll use nearest-neighbor interpolation and manually re-map these values.

Comment: Does the original file have 7 bands? You cannot assign the nodata tag to more than one value per band, if it is a single band file, you should do a little algebra first, to bring all those values to one, in my opinion.

Comment: It's a single band image--it was not apparent to me that the multiple values correspond, respectively, to each band. I had hoped I could map multiple values for a single band to a single NoData value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not clear to me at the time that each `srcnodata` value corresponds to a single NoData value in a given band, i.e., `-srcnodata "1 2 3..."` indicates that `1` is the NoData value in band 1, `2` for band 2, and so on. As one commenter suggested, a solution would be to use `gdal_calc.py` or a similar map algebra procedure to collapse multiple desired NoData values to a single value, prior to using `gdalwarp`.